# Как брать значение из Entry и произвести с ними арифметические операции

Tags: python, tkinter

Все значения вводятся, но не могу их умножать и все такое. Пишет, что нельзя со строками такое делать, не знаю как перевести их во float. Помогите пожалуйста(

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Рассчитайте свой расход!")

lbl = Label(window, text="Для того, чтобы рассчитать расход введите, пожалуйста, количество 
       литров, которое Вы потратили и пройденное расстояние", font=["Times New Roman", 11])
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)
window.geometry('1000x200')
Gaas = Label(text="Количество литров:")
Gaas.grid(column=0, row=2, )
Gaas2 = Entry( width=20,)
Gaas2.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
Distance = Label(text="Пройденное расстояние:")
Distance.grid(column=0, row=4, )
Distance2 = Entry(window, width=20,)
Distance2.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
Result = Label(text="Ваш расход на 100км: ")
Result.grid(column=0, row=6)

   def func():
   g=Gaas2.get()
   d=Distance2.get()
   result=str(g/d*100)
   Gaas2.delete(0,END)
   Gaas2.insert(0,Result)


btn = Button(window, text="Расчет", bg="green", fg="white", command= func())
btn.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=S)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `g=float(Gaas2.get())
   d=float(Distance2.get())`  И `command= func` (без скобок).

Answer (score 1):

`float('1')` даст число `1.0` типа `float`, а `Entry.get()` должен вернуть введенный текст. Дальше сами.